# Gaussian Primes of the form $a^2 + 1$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Are there any primes of this sort? I know that a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is composite in $G$ iff $p$ is a sum of $2$ squares. Thus, as $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $(a^2 + 1) \in \mathbb{Z}$, by letting $p = (a^2 + 1) \in \mathbb{Z}$, clearly $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. So does it follow that, as $a^2 + 1$ is a sum of squares, that p is composite in $\mathbb{G}$? Resulting in there being NO $p$ of the desired form being prime in $\mathbb{G}$?

Comment: $a^2+1$ is not necessarily prime in $\Bbb Z$, so you can't conclude it's always composite in $\Bbb G$. But you can conclude that when $a^2+1$ is prime, it must be composite in $\Bbb G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a^2 + 1 = (a+i)(a-i)$ is always composite in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

If $a\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $a^2 + 1$ is prime for $a\in \{2i, 1+i\}$, as well as negatives and conjugates of these.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Your proof is much nicer!